# (Mac) leave core file where the executable is instead of /cores?

Tags: linux, macos, coredump

I recently found out that Mac leaves all the core file in /cores directory.
It's hard to tell what application caused the core dump if even possible.

Wonder if I can configure system to leave the cores where the executable resides as in Linux.

Thank you

Comment: This probably belongs on SuperUser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm - maybe you can edit /etc/sysctl.conf and help yourself you specifying the core_pattern?

```
kernel.core_pattern=/cores/core.%e.%p.%h.%t
```

Maybe that would help you find out more about which process was responsible for the dump

Comment: Where is that documented? No such thing is in my `sysctl.conf`, but the `sysctl(8)` utility shows this configuration variable: `kern.corefile = /cores/core.%P`

Comment: actually - yes in os x it is corefile. You can try something like: sudo sysctl -w kern.corefile="%N-%P-%U.core"

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sysctl command to edit corefile path

```
sudo sysctl -w kern.corefile=/this/is/new/path
```

By default `kern.corefile=/cores/core.%P`, `%P` refer to process id. It can be replace by `%N` => process name, `%U` => user name. You can check the source code [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/bsd/kern/kern_proc.c)

if you want to disable core dump, using the following command

```
sudo sysctl -w kern.coredump=0
```

or edit `/etc/sysctl.conf`, add this line

```
kern.coredump=0
```