# Core Dumps aren't written to /cores on Mac OS Monterey

Tags: macos, unix, signals, coredump

I've been banging my head against this for a while. Obviously read this: [Where are core dumps written on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080918/where-are-core-dumps-written-on-mac)

And [this](https://github.com/adoptium/adoptium-support/issues/98) which lead to [this](https://github.com/adoptium/temurin-build/issues/1778).

Just so we're 100% clear:

I did:

```
touch  /cores/x
rm /cores/x
```

So write permission is good.

Did

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

So cores should be generated.

But even a trivial:

```
sleep 100 & killall -SIGSEGV sleep
```

Doesn't generate a core. My current bet is that one of the filesystem protection features of the OS is giving me grief. Another possibility is that this is related to ARM (Running on an M1 Max).

Any ideas are very welcome... I even tried this unsuccessfully: [(Mac) leave core file where the executable is instead of /cores?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495305/mac-leave-core-file-where-the-executable-is-instead-of-cores)

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem on my Bigsur macbook air too...

Comment: I don't have a mac, so I can only give general advice. Did you check the `sysctl` variable `kern.coredump` mentioned in the answers to the linked question?

Comment: Thanks, yes I tried that too. It's really weird, I tried on a 3rd even older machine and nothing...

Comment: I think all information from your comments should be added to the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm currently on Mac OS Monterey. The solution suggested at https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/694233?answerId=695943022#695943022 worked for me.

A quick summary: it is now necessary to enable `com.apple.security.get-task-allow` entitlement *per executable*.

Example with `cat`:

1. Make a copy first. Required since `cat` is on a read-only filesystem.

   ```
   % cp $(which cat) cat-copy
   ```
2. Create a dummy `.entitlements` with the `com.apple.security.get-task-allow` entitlement set:

   ```
   % /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :com.apple.security.get-task-allow bool true" tmp.entitlements
   File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: tmp.entitlements
   ```
3. Re-sign `cat-copy` with those entitlements:

   ```
   % codesign -s - -f --entitlements tmp.entitlements cat-copy 
   CrashSelf: replacing existing signature
   ```

Comment: How can I enable it on `cat`?
It isn't a .app bundle and I don't sign it. In my case this is for Java which I didn't sign

Comment: @ShaiAlmog Expanded the answer.

Comment: Trying `./cat-copy`  I get: `No matching processes belonging to you were found
fish: Job 1, './cat-copy &' terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)`

Comment: Looks like you’ve started cat-copy in the background and killed it with SIGSEGV. We’re there a core file produced? Could you please stat /cores and share the output?

Comment: It looks like the copy is broken. This is the output of stat `16777232 26194 drwxrwxr-t 2 shai staff 0 64 "Jan  9 16:10:27 2022" "Jan  9 16:07:07 2022" "Jan 10 09:10:19 2022" "Sep 18 09:26:54 2021" 4096 0 0x8000 /cores`

Comment: `./cat-copy` results in:
`fish: Job 1, './cat-copy' terminated by signal SIGKILL (Forced quit)`

Comment: While I couldn't get it to work I still awarded the bounty before expiry since you made an effort. Thanks for the help and if you have an idea that would be great!